# Laravel datatable editor

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, editor

I try to use editor datatable trial fot my work. I follow [this tuto](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/editor-tutorial) but I can't get the editor buttons to work. I got this error when i add the editor function in the html function on my ClientsDataTable : $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor

See my code

index.blade.twig :

```php
@extends('dashboard.base')
@section('css')

    /*<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">*/
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/editor.bootstrap4.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.2/css/select.bootstrap4.css">
@endsection
@section('content')
    {{ $dataTable->table() }}
@endsection

@section('javascript')
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.2/js/dataTables.select.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.2/js/select.bootstrap4.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('vendor/datatables/buttons.server-side.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ mix('js/dataTables.editor.js') }}"></script>
{{--    <script src="{{ mix('js/editor.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>--}}
    <script>
        var editor;

        $(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'
                }
            });
        });

        {{ $dataTable->generateScripts() }}
    </script>
@endsection
```

ClientsDatatable :

```php
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Models\Client;
use Exception;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Button;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Column;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Editor;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Fields;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Options\Plugins\Select;
use DataTables\Database;

class ClientsDataTable extends DataTable
{
    /**
     * Build DataTable class.
     *
     * @param mixed $query Results from query() method.
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\DataTableAbstract
     */
    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        return datatables()
            ->eloquent($query);
    }

    /**
     * Get query source of dataTable.
     *
     * @param \App\Models\Client $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function query(Client $model)
    {
        return $model->newQuery();
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return Builder
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function html(): Builder
    {
        return $this->builder()
                    ->setTableId('clients-table')
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->minifiedAjax()
                    ->dom('Bfrtip')
                    ->orderBy(1)
                    ->select(true)
                    ->buttons(
                        Button::make('create')->editor('editor'),
//                        Button::make('edit')->editor('editor'),
//                        Button::make('remove')->editor('editor'),
//                        Button::make('create'),
                        Button::make('export'),
                        Button::make('print'),
                        Button::make('reset'),
                        Button::make('reload')
                    )
                    ->editor(
                        Editor::make()
                            ->fields([
                                Fields\Text::make('cli_nom1'),
                                Fields\Text::make('cli_nom2'),
                                Fields\Text::make('cli_prenom1'),
                                Fields\Text::make('cli_prenom2')
                            ])
                    );
    }

    /**
     * Get columns.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            Column::make('id'),
            Column::make('cli_nom1'),
            Column::make('cli_nom2'),
            Column::make('cli_prenom1'),
            Column::make('cli_prenom2')
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get filename for export.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function filename()
    {
        return 'Clients_' . date('YmdHis');
    }
}
```

ClientDataTableEditor.php :

```php
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Models\Client;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesEditor;

class ClientDataTableEditor extends DataTablesEditor
{
    protected $model = Client::class;

    /**
     * Get create action validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function createRules()
    {
        return [
            'cli_nom1' => 'required:' . $this->resolveModel()->getTable(),
            'cli_prenom1'  => 'required',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get edit action validation rules.
     *
     * @param Model $model
     * @return array
     */
    public function editRules(Model $model)
    {
        return [
            'cli_nom1' => 'sometimes|required' . Rule::unique($model->getTable())->ignore($model->getKey()),
            'cli_prenom1'  => 'sometimes|required',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get remove action validation rules.
     *
     * @param Model $model
     * @return array
     */
    public function removeRules(Model $model)
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

I installed all dependencies buth this code doesn't want to work !
If someone can help me, thank you

- Operating System : Ubuntu 20.04
- PHP Version : 7.4
- Laravel Version : 8.0
- Laravel-Datatables Version 9.17.1

Comment: Did you check to make sure you are including jquery before datatables in your output html?

Comment: yes, I include app.js which require jquery. If i do not import it I should have had the "$ is not defined" error i guess

Comment: edit : 
I imported my editor.datable.js files with mix.js which compiled it. I used mix.copy and it works